# How can I retrieve resized images in Flutter using Firebase's image-resizing extension?

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, image-resizing, firebase-extensions

I'm unable to retrieve the resized images from Firebase. I get the error: 'Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.'

I am able to successfully upload my image files to firebase storage with the below function.

```
Future<String> uploadResizedData(String image, Uint8List data) async {

  //UPLOADS IMAGES TO FIREBASE STORAGE BUCKET WITH IMAGE RESIZE EXTENSION INSTALLED
  final storage = FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(bucket: 'resized');
  final storageRef = storage.ref().child(image);
  final metadata = SettableMetadata(contentType: mime(image));
  final result = await storageRef.putData(data, metadata);

//ATTEMPS TO FETCH RESIZED IMAGE
  if (result.state == TaskState.success) {
    final resizedImagePath =
        '${path.basenameWithoutExtension(image)}_200x200.jpeg';
    final resizedImageRef = storage.ref(resizedImagePath);
    final resizedImageDownloadURL = await resizedImageRef.getDownloadURL();
    return resizedImageDownloadURL;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I use a separate storage bucket for resized images called 'resized'. It uploads the images and resizes them to have dimensions of 200x200. This is all happening as expected, as I can see the resized images in my firebase storage bucket. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to access and download these images.

In the second half of the function:

```
if (result.state == TaskState.success) {
    final resizedImagePath =
        '${path.basenameWithoutExtension(image)}_200x200.jpeg';
    final resizedImageRef = storage.ref(resizedImagePath);
    final resizedImageDownloadURL = await resizedImageRef.getDownloadURL();
    return resizedImageDownloadURL;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
```

I take the path of the originally uploaded `image`, and then get the part of path after the last separator, and without any trailing file extension (using `path.basenameWithoutExtension`). This allows me to add `_200x200.jpeg` to the end of the image to ensure I'm getting the correctly resized image.

I use the same storage reference as the originally uploaded image and try to fetch this resized image's download url.

I'm left with this error: `Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/object-not-found\] No object exists at the desired reference.` It might have to do with requiring access to a new access token for the resized images, but I've been unable to figure out how to access that either.

Any help is appreciated!

Resize-image extension: https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/storage-resize-images

Comment: Do you have the the image resize extension set to delete the original image?  If so then the reference to the original image won't be valid after the extension has completed it's processing.